# Find Vs and the power supplied by the 10V source

Tags: voltage-divider, kirchhoffs-laws, current-divider

I am stuck on this textbook problem where the chapter is about Kirchhoff's Laws (Ohms, KCL, KVL, Voltage Division, Current Division, Wye-Delta, and lastly Dependent Sources).

The chapter does not cover Nodal/Mesh Analysis so I did not want to resort to that method.

Can someone enlighten me on how to get the final answer? I have tried to do a delta to wye transformation. I think I am getting messed up on the 3 amp current source being in series with the 4 ohm resistor.

[image: Basic Engineering Circuit Analysis J. David Irwin]

Comment: Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691586/circuit-theory-basic-problem/691595#691595